# How Do I Read And Parse XML From A TCP Stream?

Tags: c#, xml, tcp, stream

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question! This is my first post, so please excuse me if i did something wrong forum wise :)

**EDIT**: I appear to have solved my problem. I simply read the TCP stream 1 line at a time, and from there I use if statements to determine the reading start and stop spots.

Updated Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

namespace RFLY_CMD
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 7362);
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            while (true)
            {
                ClientWorking cw = new ClientWorking(server.AcceptTcpClient());
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(cw.DoSomethingWithClient)).Start();
            }
        }
    }

    class ClientWorking
    {
        private Stream ClientStream;
        private TcpClient Client;

        public ClientWorking(TcpClient Client)
        {
            this.Client = Client;
            ClientStream = Client.GetStream();
        }

        public void DoSomethingWithClient()
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ClientStream);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sw.BaseStream);
            string data;
            bool cap = false;
            string full_string = null;
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    data = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) || cap)
                    {
                        if(data == "... start")
                        {
                            cap = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("---START FOUND!!!---");
                        }

                        if (cap)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(data);
                            full_string += data + "--:BREAK:--";
                        }

                        if (data == "... end")
                        {
                            cap = false;

                            Console.WriteLine("---END FOUND!!!---");
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("-------------FULL STRING-------------");
                            Console.WriteLine(full_string);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.Write("Ending...");
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Working Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPa18.png)
**End Edit.**

Ok, so here is the problem... I have an application sending XML like so:

[XML Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVj15.png)

But, I only need the string of the text in the red box shown here:

[Target Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxrt3.png)

This is my first time dealing with XML and I have a little experience with TCP. Other than that, I am in WAY over my head.
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace RFLY_CMD
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7362);
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Started.");
            while (true)
            {
                ClientWorking cw = new ClientWorking(server.AcceptTcpClient());
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(cw.DoSomethingWithClient)).Start();
            }
        }
    }

class ClientWorking
{
    private Stream ClientStream;
    private TcpClient Client;

    public ClientWorking(TcpClient Client)
    {
        this.Client = Client;
        ClientStream = Client.GetStream();
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithClient()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ClientStream);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sw.BaseStream);
        string data;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
                {
                    //Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                    //Console.WriteLine("---------------");
                }
                sr.DiscardBufferedData();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Write("Ending...");
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you get from your code currently? An error or no output at all?

Comment: Code will not work!!! Cannot tell when you really get to the data.TCP breaks message into datagrams (max 1500 bytes) Without a byte count or terminating character code will not reliably tell when you get to end of the data.To read Xml from string use the Parse() method instead of the Load() method.Parse() will give exception if you do not give it the entire XML.Code is also remove spaces from the middle of a message. Possible (pretty remote) that you get a datagram with one byte (a space) which is in the innertext of an element or even removing spaces between attributes causing parsing errors.